# How can I exclude React Refresh from the Create-React-App production build?

Tags: reactjs, build, package.json, react-refresh

`Uncaught Error: React Refresh runtime should not be included in the production bundle.`

By default, when you do a `npm run build`, it changes the environment to 'production'. After looking at react-refresh,  if the environment is in production, it throws an error  that it shouldn't be included.

I have setup a `.env` file with these environment variables but when I build and serve it locally, I still get the issue. After reading up on the issue, I noticed that setting the environment variables should resolve the issue but it is not working for me.

```
FAST_REFRESH=false
REACT_APP_FAST_REFRESH=false
```

Can someone  please help me with this issue?

Comment: Did you try to move react-refresh to devDependencies in your package.json?

Comment: Another solution: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/code-splitting/

Answer (score 0):

In`babel.config.js`, you should add:

```js
const isEnvDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'

if (isEnvDev) {
  config.plugins.push('react-refresh/babel')
}
```

In`webpack.config.js`, you should add:

```js
  const isEnvDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'

  if (isEnvDev) {
    config.plugins.push(
      new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin({
        overlay: false,
      }),
    )
  }
```

and the`config.plugins`is webpack's config